# plutil returns error when a string numeric key is used

Tags: macos, bash, plist

I'm trying to insert a row to a plist by using the following command

`plutil -insert "160" -string "hi" file.plist`

However the system was not so happy about the fact that I was using a numeric key (even in string format.) This command should be correct because I tried other things like

`plutil -insert "thisistext" -string "hi" file.plist`

and they worked.

I read the man page and it said

> a numerical path component applied to an array will act on the
>   object at that index in the array or insert it into the array if the
>   numerical path component is the last one in the key path

Looks like terminal interpreted 160 as an array index despite the fact that I had double quotes surrounding it. That's why I got an out of bounds error?

```
Index 18446744073709551615 out of bounds; string length 4
```

Is there any way I can use string numbers as keys? Xcode can do the job, but I need to get it done in terminal.

Comment: duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/210956/7057

Comment: @glennjackman If you looked just a bit more closely youd be able to see that I asked both questions, and youre marking both of them as duplicate of each other... Are you a bot?

Comment: It's pretty rude to cross post. If I spent time researching an answer, then noticed better answers on the other site, I'd be pissed that I wasted my time.